# Can not read property of array inside forEach push function

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, foreach

When running the function `separateInformationToObjects` It can not read the property of array inside forEach push function.

In the function `separateInformationToObjects` the array names ( `marketDataUSDPricesObjectProperties` and `marketDataUSDRelativeObjectProperties`)  do not get highlighted as it is being used, like the other names.

I'm using javascript and nodeJS

Calling the function:

```
        separateInformationToObjects(marketDataUSD, particleDataAll,particlePriceDataAll,particleVolumeDataAll, particleMarketCapDataAll,marketDataUSDPricesObjectProperties,marketDataUSDRelativeObjectProperties)
```

Array properties:

```
let marketDataUSDRelativeObjectProperties = [
    "price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency_relative_percentage",
    "price_change_percentage_24h_in_currency_relative_percentage",
    "price_change_percentage_7d_in_currency_relative_percentage",
    "price_change_percentage_30d_in_currency_relative_percentage",
    "price_change_percentage_200d_in_currency_relative_percentage",
    "price_change_percentage_1y_in_currency_relative_percentage"
]
```

Function

```
   function separateInformationToObjects (marketDataUSD, particleDataAll,particlePriceDataAll,particleVolumeDataAll, particleMarketCapDataAll,marketDataUSDPricesObjectProperties,marketDataUSDRelativeObjectProperties) {
        //Push separate information to designated array
        particlePriceDataAll.forEach((array, index) => {
            marketDataUSD.forEach((coin) => {
                array.push({
                    "id": coin.id,
                    "particleInfo": coin.marketDataUSDPricesObjectProperties[index],
                    "relativePercentage": coin.marketDataUSDRelativeObjectProperties[index]
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

ParticleDatAll is a array of arrays:

```
let particleDataPrice1h = [],
    particleDataPrice24h = [],
    particleDataPrice7d = [],
    particleDataPrice30d = [],
    particleDataPrice200d = [],
    particleDataPrice1y = [];

let particlePriceDataAll = [particleDataPrice1h, particleDataPrice24h,particleDataPrice7d ,particleDataPrice30d, particleDataPrice200d, particleDataPrice1y]
```

Error

```
(node:9003) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at marketDataUSD.forEach ()
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at particlePriceDataAll.forEach ()
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at separateInformationToObjects ()
    at getSparklineData.then.sparklineTimeFrameResults ()
(node:9003) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9003) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Im pretty sure that stack trace was more verbose than you are providing

Comment: Either `coin.marketDataUSDPricesObjectProperties` or `coin.marketDataUSDRelativeObjectProperties` are undefined.

Comment: What is inside the array `particlePriceDataAll`

Comment: @Aplet123 Why are they undefined? I have added them into the function parameters

Comment: @Sam I have edited my question with the array data of particlePriceDataAll

Comment: @GetSet I have edited the error message

Comment: By looking at the code and as @Aplet123 marked up you don't have defined neither `coin.marketDataUSDPricesObjectProperties` nor `coin.marketDataUSDRelativeObjectProperties`; what you have defined is `marketDataUSDPricesObjectProperties` and `marketDataUSDRelativeObjectProperties`which are different objects. So just try to remove the `coin.` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function code at line 7 & 8 you need to do `coin[marketDataUSDPricesObjectProperties[index]]` and `coin[marketDataUSDRelativeObjectProperties[index]]`.

Example: you want to add the attribute `hello` with the value of `world` to the `obj` variable, by using `x`.

Don't do this:

```
var obj = {}, x = 'hello';
obj.x = 'world';

console.log(obj);

// Output: { x: 'hello' }
```

Do this:

```
var obj = {}, x = 'hello';
obj[x] = 'world';

console.log(obj);

// Output: { hello: 'world' }
```